# How to access design Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Pretty much new to Windows Forms, I know the C# language, just not in the same context. I have searched around for a while and it seems to me that every solution is doing something similar to this:

```
Label1.Text = "I'm a label".
```

But I don't understand where `Label1` is coming from.
All I have is a new Windows Form Application, which comes with one form preloaded and a Program class. So as this class came with some code, I thought this would be a logical way of accessing the label's properties:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        FormUpdate frmUpdate = new FormUpdate();

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(frmUpdate);

        // Why isn't this a suitable way of getting the label?
        frmUpdate.label1.Text = "I cause an error!";
    }
}
```

Comment: I would guess because forms have to run within the context of an `Application` object. That means all activity in the form has to take place within the call to `Application.Run`.

Comment: Also noting that form controls have `private` as the default [access modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers)

Comment: A Forms project has a designer cs file where controls are added during the Constructor of the form (Initialize).  You should not put any code into the Program.Cs file.  To add an object to the form you have to do it after it gets constructed.  The Form has a block in the constructor so it doesn't terminate.  So your code will never be executed.  The Initialize method in the form constructs all the controls like your label.

Comment: Got it, thank you all. I just thought `Program.cs` would be something you could delete so rather than making another class I started programming in there. I have since found the `Designer.cs`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But I don't understand where Label1 is coming from.

Someone used the Visual Studio Designer for Windows Forms and dragged and dropped a `Label` component onto their form. As Visual Studio has no way of naming them, but needs a name, it simply counts up. The first dropped label is called "Label1".

The access specifier for those controls added is `private` by default and I'd suggest to leave it that way. If you want to interact with your form, either do it from inside your form or write a public method that you call that will then set all the private properties like the text of a certain label.

Generally speaking, `Application.Run(frmUpdate);` is running the program, based on the starting form you gave. Anything *after* that will have little effect. So you ran your form and *after* you closed it, you set the label. That's not going to have any visible effect. You need to do that *before* you run the form or while you are running it.

Comment: I understand where `Label1` was coming from, I just didn't know the context of where it was getting it from. Sorry for my poor phrasing, I have since removed all the stuff out of the `Program.cs` file and put it over to the form.

Comment: _The first dropped label is called "Label1"._ Actually it is called `label1`. They promise to fix the bug in the fall vs-rollout..